# Como usar Blade-Laravel em um projeto MVC que não está rodando com Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, standalone

Temos aqui na empresa um grande sistema em produção que precisa ser refeito 100%.

Entre muitas discussões e indefinições ainda não se chegou a uma conclusão do framework que será usado.

No momento estamos usando uma arquitetura MVC mas sem nenhum framework. Para as nossas views estamos usando [mustache](https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php/wiki/Mustache-Tags). Eu gostaria de testar algumas views usando o Blade das últimas versões do Laravel (5.4 ou 5.5).

Alguém sabe se existe alguma maneira de instalar?

Answer (score 1):

O blade é um template engine que é provido apenas com o Laravel

Mas existem alguns projetos de extração deste para ser utilizado fora do laravel, mas nunca usei então não tenho como afirmar sobre seu desempenho

Seguem dois exemplos:

http://github.com/jenssegers/blade

http://github.com/XiaoLer/blade